# What is the simplest Spring Kafka @KafkaListener configuration to consume all records from a set of compacted topics?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have the names of several compacted Kafka topics (`topic1`, `topic2`, ..., `topicN`) defined in my spring application.yaml file. I want to be able to **consume all of the records on each topic partition** on startup. The number of partitions on each topic is not known in advance.

The official Spring Kafka 2.6.1 documentation suggests the simplest way to do this is to [implement a PartitionFinder and use it in a SpEL expresssion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.1/reference/html/#tip-assign-all-parts) to dynamically look up the number of partitions for a topic, and to then use a `*` wildcard in the partitions attribute of a `@TopicPartition` annotation (see *Explicit Partition Assignment* in the [@KafkaListener Annotation documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.1/reference/html/#kafka-listener-annotation)):

```
@KafkaListener(topicPartitions = @TopicPartition(topic = "compacted",
            partitions = "#{@finder.partitions('compacted')}"),
            partitionOffsets = @PartitionOffset(partition = "*", initialOffset = "0")))
public void listen(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key, String payload) {
    // process record
}
```

Since I have several topics, the resulting code is very verbose:

```
@KafkaListener(topicPartitions = {
        @TopicPartition(
                topic = "${topic1}",
                partitions = "#{@finder.partitions('${topic1}')}",
                partitionOffsets = @PartitionOffset(partition = "*", initialOffset = "0")
        ),
        @TopicPartition(
                topic = "${topic2}",
                partitions = "#{@finder.partitions('${topic2}')}",
                partitionOffsets = @PartitionOffset(partition = "*", initialOffset = "0")
        ),
        // and many more @TopicPartitions...
        @TopicPartition(
                topic = "${topicN}",
                partitions = "#{@finder.partitions('${topicN}')}",
                partitionOffsets = @PartitionOffset(partition = "*", initialOffset = "0")
        )
})
public void listen(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key, String payload) {
    // process record
}
```

How can I make this repetitive configuration more concise by configuring the `topicPartitions` attribute of the `@KafkaListener` annotation with a dynamically generated array of `@TopicPartion`s (one for each of my N topics)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently possible with `@KafkaListener` - please open a new feature issue on GitHub.

The only work around I can think of is to programmatically create a listener container from the container factory and create a listener adapter. I can provide an example if you need it.

**EDIT**

Here is an example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So64022266Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So64022266Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so64022266-1").partitions(10).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic2() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so64022266-2").partitions(10).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container(@Value("${topics}") String[] topics,
            PartitionFinder finder,
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory,
            MyListener listener) throws Exception {

        MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<String, String> endpoint = endpoint(topics, finder, listener);
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = factory.createListenerContainer(endpoint);
        container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("someGroup");
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<String, String> endpoint(String[] topics, PartitionFinder finder,
            MyListener listener) throws NoSuchMethodException {

        MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<String, String> endpoint = new MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<>();
        endpoint.setBean(listener);
        endpoint.setMethod(MyListener.class.getDeclaredMethod("listen", String.class, String.class));
        endpoint.setTopicPartitions(Arrays.stream(topics)
            .flatMap(topic -> finder.partitions(topic))
            .toArray(TopicPartitionOffset[]::new));
        endpoint.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(methodFactory());
        return endpoint;
    }

    @Bean
    DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory methodFactory() {
        return new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template,
            ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container) {

        return args -> {
            System.out.println(container.getAssignedPartitions());
            template.send("so64022266-1", "key1", "foo");
            template.send("so64022266-2", "key2", "bar");
        };
    }

}

@Component
class MyListener {

    public void listen(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key, String payload) {
        System.out.println(key + ":" + payload);
    }

}

@Component
class PartitionFinder {

    private final ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory;

    public PartitionFinder(ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory) {
        this.consumerFactory = consumerFactory;
    }

    public Stream<TopicPartitionOffset> partitions(String topic) {
        System.out.println("+" + topic + "+");
        try (Consumer<String, String> consumer = consumerFactory.createConsumer()) {
            return consumer.partitionsFor(topic).stream()
                    .map(part -> new TopicPartitionOffset(topic, part.partition(), 0L));
        }
    }

}
```

```
topics=so64022266-1, so64022266-2
```

If you need to deal with tombstone records (`null` values) we need to enhance the handler factory; we currently don't expose the framework's handler factory.

Comment: Will raise a feature request, and live with the current approach for now - but if you do find time to provide a basic example of a listener adapter and container to make this more elegant in the meantime, that would be very interesting!

Comment: I added an example of programmatically creating the endpoint/listener.